# Is getting rid of the dough the only solution when it smells of yeast?

Tags: dough, pizza, yeast, smell

I made pizza dough (it was ready to use, you just add the liquid ingredients -oil and milk in my case- and the rest is similar to the usual process of letting it rest and so on) the other day and left it in the fridge for about 48 hours, when I was making pizza I figured it smells of yeast which is unpleasant and quite strong. Anything can be done about it or tossing in the trash is the only solution to the issue?

Comment: What temperature is your fridge?

Comment: Forgot to ask: Is the dough mix supposed to go in the fridge, or is it a mix - raise on counter - bake type.

Answer (score 4):

Hmm. A yeast dough smelling of yeast. There's only one solution - bake it.

Comment: I think the OP is probably smelling more fermentation than she's used to ("unpleasant and quite strong"), not just everyday yeast smell. Probably still fine to bake, of course; a couple days in a fridge shouldn't produce insane fermentation.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like making a biga or poolish: it might serve as a starter for new dough. You could mix it with fresh flour and water.

Answer (score 3):

Smelling of yeast is not a bad thing. This dough is fine, it's a pre-ferment. Too much of a yeasty smell only means that the live yeast are running out of food. So add some flour to it, knead it, let it rise again, shape and bake.  It will be delicious.